# Clickhouse datatype analog for Oracle Number datatype

Tags: oracle, scala, numbers, clickhouse

(Clickhouse - 23.11.2.11, Oracle - 11.2.0.3.0).
My task is load data from Oracle table into Clickhouse table (with using scala code).

In oracle the table was crated with script:

```
create table EAIST_LOT_SS
(
  id             NUMBER not null,
  registrynumber VARCHAR2(19) not null,
  tendersubject  VARCHAR2(2048),
  lotnumber      NUMBER not null,
  lotprice       NUMBER
);

column COLUMN_NAME format a15
column DATA_TYPE format a15

select column_name, data_type, nullable, data_length, data_precision, data_scale
from user_tab_columns where table_name ='EAIST_LOT_SS';

COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE       NULLABLE DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
--------------- --------------- -------- ----------- -------------- ----------
ID              NUMBER          N                 22                
REGISTRYNUMBER  VARCHAR2        N                 19                
TENDERSUBJECT   VARCHAR2        Y               2048                
LOTNUMBER       NUMBER          N                 22                
LOTPRICE        NUMBER          Y                 22
```

In clickhouse the table was crated with script:

```
create table data.eaist_lot
(
  id                  UInt8 not null,
  registrynumber      FixedString(19) not null,
  tendersubject       FixedString(2048),
  lotnumber           Decimal64(18) not null,
  lotprice            Decimal64(18)
)ENGINE = MergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

scala code, try add one row into table.

```
  def saveToClickhouse(table: String, chConn: ClickHouseConnection): Unit = {
    val ps: PreparedStatement = chConn.prepareStatement(
      s"""insert into ${table}
        |select id, registrynumber, tendersubject, lotnumber, lotprice
        |from
        |input('id             UInt8,
        |       registrynumber FixedString(19),
        |       tendersubject  FixedString(2048),
        |       lotnumber      Decimal64(18),
        |       lotprice       Decimal64(18)
        |      ')
        |""".stripMargin)

    ps.setInt(1,1)
    ps.setString(2,"str 222")
    ps.setString(3,"str 333")
    ps.setDouble(4,1.2)
    ps.setDouble(5,2.3)

    ps.addBatch()
    ps.executeBatch()
  }
```

I have error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BigDecimal(1200000000000000000.0) should be between -1000000000000000000 and 1000000000000000000 exclusive of both values

What the best analog on Number (without setting precision and scale) in Clickhouse?

Comment: It would be way more helpful to know what your data actually looks like, instead of what Oracle data types you used. For example, is tendersubject always 2048 characters, or is that just a maximum size? If it's just a max size, then it would be better to use String instead of FixedString.  Are lotnumber and lotprice really that large of numbers that you need 18 digits past the decimal? Or are they simply integers, in which case UInt64 would work much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, a [`NUMBER` data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78) is:

> #### Built-in Data Type Summary
>
> | Code | Data Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | `NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]` | Number having precision `p` and scale `s`. The precision `p` can range from 1 to 38. The scale `s` can range from -84 to 127. Both precision and scale are in decimal digits. A `NUMBER` value requires from 1 to 22 bytes. |

...

> Specify an integer using the following form:
>
> ```sql
> NUMBER(p)
> ```
>
> This represents a fixed-point number with precision `p` and scale `0` and is equivalent to `NUMBER(p,0)`.
>
> Specify a floating-point number using the following form:
>
> ```sql
> NUMBER
> ```
>
> The absence of precision and scale designators specifies the maximum range and precision for an Oracle number.

Therefore, `NUMBER` without specifying precision or scale is equivalent to `NUMBER(38,*)` which has the maximum precision and an unspecified scale and is an exact floating-point number.

---

[Clickhouse includes the numeric data types](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types):

> - Integer types: signed and unsigned integers (UInt8, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt128, UInt256, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int128, Int256)
> - Floating-point numbers: floats(Float32 and Float64) and Decimal values

Where the `DECIMAL` documentation states:

> Signed fixed-point numbers that keep precision during add, subtract and multiply operations. For division least significant digits are discarded (not rounded).
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - `P` - precision. Valid range: [ 1 : 76 ]. Determines how many decimal digits number can have (including fraction). By default the precision is 10.
> - `S` - scale. Valid range: [ 0 : P ]. Determines how many decimal digits fraction can have.
>
> `Decimal(P)` is equivalent to `Decimal(P, 0)`. Similarly, the syntax `Decimal` is equivalent to `Decimal(10, 0)`.
>
> Depending on P parameter value Decimal(P, S) is a synonym for:
>
> - `P` from [ 1 : 9 ] - for `Decimal32(S)`
> - `P` from [ 10 : 18 ] - for `Decimal64(S)`
> - `P` from [ 19 : 38 ] - for `Decimal128(S)`
> - `P` from [ 39 : 76 ] - for `Decimal256(S)`

Therefore `DECIMAL` is a fixed-point number.

---

Clickhouse does not appear to have an equivalent data-type that is the same as Oracle's `NUMBER` data-type.

You should look at the data contained in your `NUMBER` column:

- If your column contains only integer values then you are effectively using `NUMBER` as `NUMBER(38,0)` and in Clickhouse that could be  `Int128` or `UInt128`.
- If your number column contains fixed-point decimal values and it would have been appropriate to specify the column as `NUMBER(38, s)` then in Clickhouse that would be `Decimal128(s)` (assuming 0 ≤ `s` ≤ 38).
- If you really are using the full range of precision and scale that `NUMBER` (or `NUMBER(38,*)`) supports in Oracle then Clickhouse does not appear to support that range of values and you could use `Float64` to approximate the value or could store the value as a string.